# Sorting in Text and Number column vb.net NATURAL SORT

Tags: sql, vb.net, sorting, natural-sort

I have a text and numeric data in a column of excel. data is 1,2,3,A,B,C,D,10,11,12. I want to do sort these by SQL. and i want get data in below order 1,2,3,10,11,12,A,B,C,D.

So please can any one suggest how i do this.
[image]

Comment: Do you have this data entered in a table?

Comment: Yes. I have data in Excel sheet.

Comment: Why is this tagged SQL?  It is an Excel question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Its tagged SQL bcoz i am firing SQL command to get data from excel. so

Comment: Can you explain this: _"I have  text and numeric data in a column of excel, i want to do sort it by **SQL**."_

Comment: @Arion Its a simple SQL query. I want to sort a particular column.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have 1,2,3,A,B,C,D,10,11,12. in a text type column (Row wise)Row1-1, Row2-2, Row3-3, Row4-A and so on....

Comment: @MiteshKhatri: Then this is a SQL question and has nothing to do with excel. Then you should tag the dbms with it's version(f.e. SQL-Server 2005). What is with values like `123abc`, `abc123` and `0200abc`? Can you show sample data with extreme cases and your desired result?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have added image for data in my question. Please check and give me suggestion. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Because SQL does not store items with any order, the order by clause can be used to return items in a specific order that is needed.

if you are already using an order_by clause, but are getting the wrong order, the order they are returned depends on the collation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx

You want your list sorted in ascending order, so you can use something like:

```
Select * from table ORDER BY order_by_expression
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN Asc
```

Hope this works!